# How to pass Date to Datatime lightning inputfield

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-experience

Hi i have a problem with passing data into the lightning:inputField. Its inputfield of type Datetime and i want to have a function, when somebody pick Yes from picklist, it will automatically populate field Date_of_PU__c with current date and time.

cmp

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="puDate" fieldName="Date_of_PU__c" variant="label-hidden" id="{!indx}" onchange="{!c.cellValueMassChanged}" />
```

controller js

```
cellValueChanged : function (cmp, event, helper){

        var sourceValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");
        if ((sourceValue == 'Yes') || (sourceValue == 'Ano') ) {
            var date = cmp.find('v.puDate');
            var today = new Date();
            console.log('datum ' + today);
            cmp.set(data, today);    
        }
```

I am getting error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Comment: Can you also provide code for cellValueMassChanged ?

Comment: I see few issues in your code unless those are just typo or incomplete code. `cmp.find('v.puDate');` -- this should be instead `cmp.find("puDate");`. You use find to look for a component based on its `aura:id`. Also you need to remove `id` from the input field, as don't think that solves any purpose here.

Comment: You have many syntax errors in your code, please go over the code and fix all (like `data` and method name `cellValueChanged`) then post your question